# Better way to get first argv

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need fast and good way (or library) to use first argument after I do `python3.6 test.py some_argument`.

```
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    argument_i_want = sys.argv[1]
```

Is there a way to do something like:
`argument_i_want = some_lib.get_first_or_empty()`

Comment: I would be very surprised if someone wrote a library to reduce 2 lines of code to 1...

Comment: you can go for a library when you have a bigger functionality. But when the functionality is as small as a if condition, I suggest to go ahead with this itself!

Comment: ternary operator: `argument_i_want = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) else ''`

Comment: If there is some chance that you may be adding other options later, consider using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) instead, setting defaults for positional arguments.

Comment: Marking as duplicate because `sys.argv` is just a `list`. There is no canonical solution. I find it odd that this doesn't exist too (we have `dict.get(key, default)` after all) but that's the way it is.

Comment: What I sometimes do is `height_wrap = argv[1:2]`, and then `if height_wrap: [height] = height_wrap`.  In Python 3.5+ you also can use `_cmd, *height_wrap = argv`.

Comment: You could convert your `argv` to a `dict` first:  `dict(enumerate(argv)).get(1, 'default')`  (just kidding, even if that works ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use `try-catch`

**Ex:**

```
import sys

try:
    argument_i_want = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    argument_i_want = ""
```

Comment: Good but still this is even longer, I wonder if there is one liner...